# Let $f: M_{m\times n} \to M_{n\times n}$ be given by $f(A) = A^tA$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable and find a formula for $f'(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $f: M_{m\times n} \to M_{n\times n}$ be given by  $f(A) = A^tA$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable and find a formula for $f'(A)$.

I am a little confused on this problem. First of all, the definition of differentiation I have involves subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in both the domain and range. Does the same definition apply for functions in matrix spaces?

By that definition, if I can show there exists $T \in L(M_{m\times n}, M_{n\times n})$ such that $${\lim_{h\to 0} {f(a+h) - f(a) - T(h)}\over {||h||}} = 0.$$ But I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about this. How do I prove $f$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F(A+ \Delta) = F(A)+A^T \Delta + \Delta^T A + 
\Delta^T \Delta$.

I will use the Frobenius norm as it is convenient and submultiplicative. The proof works with any other norm, but may need different constants.

To show that $F$ is differentiable, we need to find a linear function $L: M_{m\times n} \to M_{n\times n}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $\|\Delta\| < \delta$, then
$\|F(A+ \Delta)-F(A)-L (\Delta) \| \le \epsilon \|\Delta\|$.

The above expansion suggests that $L(\Delta) = A^T \Delta + \Delta^T A$, then we need to find a $\delta>0$ such that if $\|\Delta\| < \delta$, then$\|\Delta^T \Delta \| \le \epsilon \|\Delta\|$. Since $\|\Delta^T \Delta \| \le \|\Delta\|^2$, If we choose $\delta = \epsilon$ we obtain the desired result.